# Game object ownership not transferring and getting destroyed with the master client

Tags: unity, c#, multiplayer, photon

I'm using photon pun. I have a spawner script which instantiates the eatables in the gameplay and right after the instantiation, im transferring its ownership to null. The instantiated game objects's photon view component's ownership transfer variable is set to takeover.

But, my instantiated game object is still getting destroyed with the master client, how do i stop this from happening? Also I don't have any `IPunOwnershipCallbacks` in the instantiated game object script.

Comment: From the example of pun `By default, all GameObjects created by one player will be destroyed when he/she leaves.` Are you using local multiplayer? Because when the server is the master client, you have a different problem if that one is disconnecting. Did you create the GameObjects with `InstantiateSceneObject()`? Or try setting `PhotonNetwork.autoCleanUpPlayerObjects` to false. But with no more code from you, we can only guess

Comment: @Zibelas Thank you for the comment. I did find a post mentioning the `PhotonNetwork.autoCleanUpPlayerObjects`. Although this was missing for me. Then I stumbled upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68358311/missing-photonnetwork-autocleanupplayerobjects) and it finally worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to have solved it. In the create room options, I set the variable `CleanupCacheOnLeave` to false. Now the game objects weren't getting destroyed when the master left and the ownership under the photon view component, I left it to fixed.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68358311/missing-photonnetwork-autocleanupplayerobjects) post which got it working for me